# Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80 OSx Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I'm following a tutorial in a angularJS book and have to setup a server. This is the server.js file:

```
 var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
   app.use('/', express.static('./'));
    app.listen(80);
```

I get this error:

```
$ node server.js
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
```

I know already, that the Error EACCES means that i don't have access rights to the port 80, but i don't know how to fix this.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: change the port to something > 1024, e.g. `app.listen(8080)` or start the server as root, `sudo node server.js`.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you @georg i changed the port. Dow you know why i get this error with the port 80?

Comment: On many systems you need to be `root` (or similar) to open the ports below 1024.  So your choices are pick a port above 1024 or, if you have the permissions, run your code as `root`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you need to run the server on port 80 you should use a reverse proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org/) that will run using a system account on a privileged port and proxy the requests to your Node.js server running on an unprivileged port (> 1024).

When running in development environment you're pretty much free to run as root (ie. `sudo node server.js`), but that is rather dangerous in production environment.

Here's a sample nginx config that will see if the request is for a file that exists in the filesystem, and if not, proxy the request to your Node.js server running on port 9000

```
upstream yournodeapp {
  server localhost:9000 fail_timeout=0;
  keepalive 60;
}

server {
  server_name localhost;
  listen 80 default_server;

  # Serve static assets from this folder
  root /home/user/project/public;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @yournodeapp;
  }

  location @yournodeapp {
    proxy_pass http://yournodeapp;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Comment: ugh. isn't there some way to proxy using node itself?

Comment: Nginx or Apache is not necessary. There is a great number of Node proxies: [redbird](https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird), [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware). To fix the above issue you most likely  need to SUDO script execution: `sudo node server.js`

Comment: @Michael see my answer below... using node itself

Answer (score 47):

to give root access to node and start server on port 80
you can do

```
sudo node app.js
```

this will start the server giving permission on port 80

Comment: Advising to run as root introduces unnecessary security risks. This is ill-advised.

Answer (score 20):

**Foremost, do not run as root.** That's asking for 'it'. "It" is really bad. Go see [the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdg193GvnBA). Then, don't run your node web project as root.

```
// DO NOT DO THIS!
$ sudo node app.js

// DO NOT DO THIS EITHER!
$ sudo su -
# node app.js
```

Instead, use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and [authbind](https://medium.com/@steve.mu.dev/setup-authbind-on-mac-os-6aee72cb828) to do this:

```
// %user% is whatever user is running your code
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

Next, add this alias to your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias pm2='authbind --deep pm2'
```

Then, try it with pm2:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Comment: touch: cannot touch ‘/etc/authbind/byport/80’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I fixed this by setting Express to listen on port 8080 for HTTP and 8443 for HTTPS.  It really doesn't like using those lower number ports. Also I have IIS installed and running so it might be some sort of port conflict there too.

Comment: IIS usually grabs port 80 for the Default site.

Answer (score 0):

there is

**sudo ufw allow 80/tcp**

and it should be port forwarded, worked for me atleast