# what is 'Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:7090'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm doing to run nodejs server on windows server 2012. App port is 7090. This is part of the server.js file:

```
var port    = process.env.PORT || 7090;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

When I run it with `node server.js` ,I get this error:

```
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:7090
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1031:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1240:19)
    at listen (net.js:1289:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1385:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (D:\STH\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\STH\app.js:26:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

​It works when I change port to any other numbers except 7090.

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:7090
I know already, that the Error EACCES means that i don't have access rights to the port 7090 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068712/error-listen-eacces-0-0-0-080-osx-node-js) question, but i don't know how to fix this. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Is something already listening on 7090?

Comment: Netsh http add urlacl

Comment: My guess is that you're running some sort of antivirus or firewall that is blocking your Node app from listening on port 7090.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed! That port is already listening by IISNode unexpectedly. I just deleted it and now ok to run on port 7090.

Comment: I also running with the same issue, how you deleted it ?

Comment: @K.S are u running IISNode on your Windows server?

Comment: Yes, it is remote windows sever 12

Comment: I am trying to run on port 8000 but its show permission denied access, could you help me?

Comment: if u r running IISNode, just find and remove it from widows server. that's what i did as my solution. and don't use windows web server to run node app. just run Node application as a Windows service using the tools like https://nssm.cc or https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows

Answer (score 1):

this means that something else (probably your app) is already running on that port. Maybe you run it in background or as another user and can't restore it right now. You can look up who is using the port by using netstat on windows server: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961504(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: You'd expect `EADDRINUSE` when there's already something listening on that port, instead of `EACCES` (although the former might be Unix-only).

Comment: when I check with netstat -anb , i have this message -   Can not obtain ownership information TCP    0.0.0.0:7090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING . is that mean it's already listening something?

Answer (score 1):

`lsof -i:7090`

Find the PID then

`kill -9 PID`

Comment: i am on windows, can't use lsof

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying to run node app on server I got the same issue, but fortunately after did little search I found the solution And I used node command as a superuser, It was so simple, I know the questioner got the answer but hope this will help to some other folks.

```
sudo node your_app_name.js
```