# How to sudo inside alpine?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using the redis docker image. In `docker-entrypoint.sh`, it has these lines that forces the container to be run as `redis` user.

```
# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    chown -R redis .
    exec su-exec redis "$0" "$@"
fi
```

The problem is it causes permission problem when I want to create a folder at `/` to store the socket file.

`Opening Unix socket: bind: Permission denied`

The only folder that `redis` has permission to is `/data/` which isn't a good place to store socket file and to be accessed by other container. How do I bypass the `if` block to run redis as root?

(I am aware there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225976/use-sudo-inside-dockerfile-alpine), but it isn't answered. Also the condition is different. I am using the official docker image so I can't do anything to the Dockerfile.)

Comment: You’d generally use TCP ports to communicate between containers, not Unix sockets.  If you _really_ needed a socket you’d have to bind-mount a host directory that you could set the permissions on.

Comment: @DavidMaze How to set permissions in a host directory? The `redis` user isn't a user in the host.