# Amazon EC2 Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-ec2, vue.js, yarnpkg

I have already added the HTTP TCP Port 80 to the inbound rules, but I still get the error:

```
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1338:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1505:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: You should create or use existing nginx user with privileges to proxy all requests to port 80 rather than `sudo`-it since the latter would open a rooting options to external folks. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069615/1598355

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably have to run your node.js script with sudo as you want to listen on port 80.

Comment: FYI it's not secure solution

Comment: If I sudo node it says the command is not found

Comment: why not secure ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot run a process that listens on low ports (below 1024) without root privileges.

You either try to run as `sudo`, as stated above, or start to use a reverse proxy (nginx for instance), start the process on another port and use the reverse proxy to forward the calls from port `80` to whatever port you started the process on.

Answer (score 5):

You should *never* run a web app with root privileges!

You can use setcap to allow node to listen on privileged ports without root.

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error code EACCES means you don't have proper permissions to run applications on that port. On Linux systems, any port below 1024 requires root access.

Comment: I don't know about ports below 1024 that need to root access, thanks for your awesome information.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use reverse proxy to forward the calls from port 80 to 8080 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when attempting to executing a `node` script via an `npm` command. To fix this, I executed it directly using the `node` command. (The use of `sudo` was also required).

From:

`sudo npm run start`

To:

`sudo node index.js`